# How can I change the outline colour for my button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make the blue outline colour be #D5A021 instead of blue when the users clicks on the button?

I think it may have something to do with `btn-primary`

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Find Out More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-xl {
  padding: 1rem 2rem
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #D5A021;
  border-color: #D5A021;
}

.btn-primary:active, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #D5A021!important;
}
```

Comment: The issue should be demonstrated in the problem statement described in the question. Consider reproducing it in an embedded code snippet (look for the `<>` icon in the text editor toolbar). This will improve the question and create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) while also allowing for user-friendly troubleshooting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are looking to override the default Bootstrap classes. And if that's the case, then the following code will do what you want:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

.btn-xl {
            padding: 1rem 2rem
        }
        .btn-primary, 
        .btn-primary:hover {
            background-color: #D5A021;
            border-color: #D5A021;
        }
        .btn-primary:active,
        .btn-primary:focus {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #D5A021 !important;
            border-color: #D5A021 !important;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(213,160,33, 0.5) !important;
        }
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Find Out More <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

It's the `box-shadow` property that needs to be modified in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS **outline-color** Property, wherever you need it.

For example,

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #D5A021;
  border-color: #D5A021;
  outline-color: #D5A021;
}
```